# TFS 2017 Build: Cannot Run PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS 2017 and it has several builds configured.  A little while ago we started getting an error on the second step, which is to run a PowerShell Script (first step is Get Sources):

```
2018-06-28T19:58:59.4326443Z ##[command]. 'K:\_work\3\s\BuildScripts\MainPre.ps1' -env "test"
2018-06-28T19:58:59.6236482Z ##[error]Access is denied
2018-06-28T19:58:59.6266488Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

A build 4 hours ago worked just fine.  No changes were made to the file, or the filesystem.  I am waiting to hear from the network team to see if they did anything to the build account.

What could cause this error suddenly and how do I fix it? Note: I have not yet tried to turn it off and on again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking through the server, I noticed that the Event Viewer says Symantec SONAR was blocking the power shell scripts. After our network team added an exception for the build processes, our builds were again working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message "`##[error]Access is denied`", seems it's an permission issue.

Just try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Enable **Clean** option in **Get sources** step: Set `Clean` to
  `True` and select `Sources Directory` under `Clean options.`
- Check if the agent service account has the correct permission to
  access the script.
- Try to change another account which has the correct permission to
  access the agent _work foler as the service account, then queue build
  again.
- Deploy a new agent, try it again.

If that still not work, just turn on `system.debug` in variable tab (set to true) to capture the logs and share here for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, definitely seems to be some weird, new permissions thing, especially with the timing.  Event Viewer says Symantec SONAR is blocking it. Anything I can feed to the network guys to get it fixed that you are aware of?

Comment: @DaveJohnson Seems Symantec SONAR prevents it from running. Just try to create an exception for PowerShell.exe, then  try it again. You can also try deploying a new agent on the TFS Server itself, then check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the powershell task runs some sort of security check when executing scripts?

I ran the powershell task in DEBUG and you can see the task runs some security work implicitly here.

This does give me access denied when i run it:

```
##[debug]C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 

-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "try { $null = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData] } catch { Write-Verbose 'Adding assemly: System.Security' ; Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Security' ; $null = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData] ; $Error.Clear() } ; Invoke-Expression -Command ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAARs9EULLEBU+ppaGEeISmGgAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAABLYbw0iUTABtaCw2PJ5KrrAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAOg6VMmANxZJSRmKjPWauqRYAAAAqDSQVtB4LtvBaujeTs1GKn4CPFrW484weBNwtJ7aujcJLWV4wBLHD9n+IEVZ6z13oyIpyxUEceTtiMKnfuO8irwX9l5DoHqlMGU6mx1Q5kou2V6ITEcl0BQAAAD1h7qvkyE8+PcdKmVKLHVpqYO4mA=='), [System.Convert]::FromBase64String('8yTvn1ZlLZGC7M3ewDzbLw=='), [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser))) ; if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath variable:\LastExitCode)) { Write-Verbose 'Last exit code is not set.' } else { Write-Verbose ('$LastExitCode: {0}' -f $LastExitCode) ; exit $LastExitCode }"
2018-06-30T12:44:57.8488275Z ##
```

Answer (score 1):

For us, MCafee was blocking the powershell.  once an exception was added, we were good.